# Collecting ids in separate dataframe

Tags: python, collections, data-science, analytics

I am stuck in a situation after grouping my data through ids. Now I want
to collect them with full info with the same ids.

Current => I got this result after using group by id's.
Expected=>every same id with all info as shown in the pic

[image: OUTPUT should be like]

```py
dfs=pd.read_excel('tns1.xlsx')
grp = dfs.groupby('entity_id')
da  = grp.groups
for entity_id,show in grp:
  print(show)
  print(da)
```

Now I have expected output also but the problem is I am getting in extracting them correctly & then to write in excel using the below loop I am trying to extract but I do not think so that it is extracting properly besides it is running thousand of times as many rows are there

Comment: may we see the code you have tried so far? also paste some data samples, so it helps to reproduce.

Comment: if you want to write to csv for example, you can do like this way 'show.to_csv(f'{entity_id}.csv')' in your for loop and it will create csv for each entity.

Comment: problem is coming from loop only if i put 'show.to_csv(f'{entity_id}.csv')' this code in loop it is making thousands of files which has to come like in one file with any separator or gap.(whole data)

without loop i cannot extract grouped data and with loop it is loading infinite times

Answer (score 0):

So you can collect the individual data to list and then write it to csv.

**Data setup** for illustration:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
raw_data="""
entity_id,Name,Status,Date
2244,Abhi,Active,10-06-2021
2244,Abhi2,Blocked,10-06-2021
6666,other1,Blocked,10-06-2021
6666,other,Active,10-06-2021
"""
dfs=pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data))
```

append all the dfs in a list:

```
grp = dfs.groupby('entity_id')
da  = grp.groups
groups_as_list=[]

for entity_id,show in grp:
    groups_as_list.append(show)# append all dfs in a list
```

then write the list of dataframes to csv.

```
with open("my_results.csv","w") as f:# open file for write
    for each_df in groups_as_list:
            each_df.to_csv(f,index=False)
            f.write("\n") # write empty line to csv
```

so the result will look like the following:( you can tweak it further based on need)
[image]